# runtimeService.setVariable , is it sync or async operation?

Tags: camunda

I am seeing a strange behavior while working with runtimeService.

I have a method which does below operation to put a variable.

```
runtimeService.setVariable(execution.getId(), "KEY","VALUE");
```

I have gone into the depth of camunda internals and found out it does the commit to the target scope while inside finally block of CommandContextInterceptor

```
  try {
    if (openNew) {
      LOG.closingCommandContext();
      context.close(commandInvocationContext);
```

I just have a separate piece of block placed right after when the variable was set, and here we are reading the already set variable.

```
taskService.getVariablesTyped(taskId, deserialize);
```

The fact is 8 out of 10 times, I am able to get the variable which has been set successfully. But, 2 times, it fails to get the variable.

I can found the traces of Executor from mybatis framework to be responsible to commit the sql session.
DefaultSQLSession

```
  public void commit() {
    commit(false);
  }

  @Override
  public void commit(boolean force) {
    try {
      executor.commit(isCommitOrRollbackRequired(force));
      dirty = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw ExceptionFactory.wrapException("Error committing transaction.  Cause: " + e, e);
    } finally {
      ErrorContext.instance().reset();
    }
  }
```

Is it possible that by the time it is being committed to DB, I am trying to read it ?
Is the setVariable operation on runtimeService an atomic and completely sync operation ?

We are using camunda-engine-7.14.0-ee.jar .